# What does it mean when people say your dialogue should have its own line?

Tags: creative-writing

So, I've been trying to write a novel and some people have read it and said it was great and I've also received some criticism saying I needed to give each line of dialogue it's own line. Does it mean that I end my paragraph and start a line that starts with the dialogue and then continue a new paragraph until the next character's dialogue or do I just put the dialogue and the start a new paragraph under it. Because I'm really trying to make this novel great and getting constructive criticism helps but I'm not sure what these people mean.

Answer (score 3):

The guideline -- as there are no rules in writing -- is 'one speaker per paragraph.'  In that paragraph, along with your speaker's dialogue, you can include action beats and narrative details.

> "I say there," said a guy, scratching his nose. The other guy frowned, distressed by guy's personal habits. Guy ignored him, asking, "Is this the summer of our discontent, made glorious winter by this son of York."
>
> The other guy said, "Two monkeys walk into bar. The taller one hits her head."

The intent is to make who is speaking clear while also filling the scene so it doesn't come across the people talking in a featureless white room. Long stretches of dialogue often lose the element of setting. Action beats let the characters react to each other and the environment, helping the reader envision of moment.

I said it was a guideline. One exception is when a mob's dialogue is shared. The individual speakers aren't as important as the words they are saying.  When Paul Atriedes refuses to challenge Stilgar in Dune is a scene like that.

Another exception is that you, as the author, decide the pacing, and the moment is ruined by one speaker per paragraph. I've read award-winning literary fiction and general audience fiction where the author mushed the speakers into a single paragraph. They were fast-paced moments with intense emotion or action. In fiction, the author does what the author needs to do.